# Making a nested for loop (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

So what I am trying to do is make this "Triangle" in python with for loops:

[image: Pascal]

But with the text like so:

```
0|0
1|01
2|012
3|0123
4|01234
```

What the output that I currently have is:

```
0|01234
1|01234
2|01234
3|01234
4|01234
```

And here is the code for the output:

```
def pascal(n):
    answer = ""
    for rows in range(n):
        answer = str(rows) + "|"
        for col in range(n):
            answer = answer + str(col)
        print(answer)

pascal(5)
```

My question is, how the heck do I make the ouput do this?(Im stumped as to what im supposed to do):

```
0|0
1|01
2|012
3|0123
4|01234
```

---

If anyone would like to see what the hell I was trying to accomplish, heres my solution

Soooooooo, this blue triangle:

[image: Pascal]

turns into the pascal triangle, by "n choose k":

[image: formula]

I was trying to figure out the for loops so I can have the basic setup done(which is the blue triangle), which you guys helped with :)

So the code that I came up with to get the n choose k is this:

```
def factorial(n):
    answer = 1
    for number in range(2, n+1):
       answer = answer * number
    return answer


def pascal(n):
    answer = ""
    for rows in range(n):
        answer = ""
        for col in range(rows+1):
            answer = answer + str( int(factorial(rows) / (factorial(col)*factorial(rows-(col)))) )

        print(answer)
pascal(10)
```

The factorial() is the exclamation point in the n choose k formula and I made the rest of the formula with this code:

```
factorial(rows) / (factorial(col)*factorial(rows-(col)))
```

So any n that is greater than 0, makes a pascal triangle :)

Comment: Your code is fine, you only need to change this line: `for col in range(n):`. Shouldn't loop all the way to `n`

Comment: Actually, it should be `range(rows+1)`.  But, the entire outer loop body can be replaced with: `print(rows, "|", *range(rows+1), sep="")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. When printing each row you don't want to go all the way to `n`. The inner loop should stop at `rows`, so change `for col in range(n)` to `for col in range(rows+1)`.

```
def pascal(n):
    answer = ""
    for rows in range(n):
        answer = str(rows) + "|"
        for col in range(rows+1):
            answer = answer + str(col)
        print(answer)

pascal(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the second `for`

**Code:**

```
def pascal(n):
    answer = ""
    for rows in range(n):
        answer = str(rows) + "|"
        for col in range(rows + 1): # Modify this
            answer = answer + str(col)
        print(answer)

pascal(5)
```

**Why?** - Because your first `for` is for the number of lines, the second `for` is for the elements in that line, you don't want to loop over, let's say, `5` again, just over the correct number of elements, in this case, it will be the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was correct but your inner loop shouldn't loop to `n`. You should replace it with `rows+1`.

```
def pascal(n):
    answer = ""
    for rows in range(n):
        answer = str(rows) + "|"
        for col in range(rows+1):
            answer = answer + str(col)
        print(answer)

pascal(5)
```

output:

```
0|0
1|01
2|012
3|0123
4|01234
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't use a for loop to do this. A while loop will be much more efficient for what you want to do. For instance:

```
pascal(n):
  answer=''
  answerright = ''
  i=0
  while i <= n:
    answerright += str(i)
    answer += str(i) + '|' + answerright + '\n'
    i+=1
  return answer
```

That will generate what you're looking for, without overly complicating the code. You don't say if you are *required* to use for loops, but if not, this is the better solution. In python, all for loops are really foreach loops, always remember that.

Comment: Why I was using for loops, I have no idea. I think I was just trying to get the triangle down, like the (0/0) so I can put that into a 0,0 form to get it to use the "n choose k" sequance to make the pascal triangle. if that doesnt make sense is because i am still trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Your code is more efficient because you omitted one of the two loops, but the loop type doesn't matter much. In your code it's perfectly acceptable to interchange the while-loop for a for-loop; it would be faster and arguably cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right path:

```
for row in range (5):
  row_string = str(row) + "|"

  for i in range(row+1):
    row_string += str(i)

  print row_string
```

You only want to iterate up to the current row (+1 since we're zero-indexed here) in your inner for-loop.